# Saving data when suspending UWP app with multiple windows/views: UI Thread not responding

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a basic UWP app. The app allows users to open multiple documents at once, each in a separate window (i.e. "view").

When the app is suspended, I request an `ExtendedExecutionSession` to save changes for all documents.

However, when I try to run the save operation for a secondary window on the respective UI thread of the secondary window, the code never runs.

I suspect that's because the UI thread of the secondary window is "frozen" as soon as the app enters the `suspending` state. The code runs right after the app is resumed.

My questions:

1. What is the right way to save changes while suspending (e.g. access the file system) for a UWP app with multiple windows?
2. How can I save changes for each document in parallel to be as quick as possible to avoid that my app may gets terminated by the system (i.e. am I allowed to spawn new threads while my app is being suspended)?

**Relevant code, App.xaml.cs:**

```
    private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var l = logger.Entered("Suspending app");

        suspendDeferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();

        using (var session = new ExtendedExecutionSession())
        {
            session.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.SavingData;
            session.Description = "Saving Documents";
            session.Revoked += ExtendedExecutionSessionRevoked;

            var result = await session.RequestExtensionAsync();

            foreach (var controller in WindowController.WindowController.sharedInstance.getWindowLifetimeControls())
            {
                var l2 = logger.Entered("Window controller: " + controller);

                await controller.dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
                    // XXX never called for secondary window:
                    l2.Checkpoint("running async...");
                });

                l2.Exited();
            // […]
```

Note: the `dispatcher` above is a `Window.CoreWindow.Dispatcher`. I keep references to those for all open windows.

**Edit:**

I tried to rework my code to save synchronously when suspending, but even code like this will hang indefinitely:

```
  tempZipFile.DeleteAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Could you show more detail about `WindowController` or share a simple sample to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT My `WindowController` code is modeled after: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/MultipleViews/cs/ViewLifetimeControl.cs